# Othello Minimax Algorithm Doesn't Work In React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, minimax

I have this issue where the AI player always plays the first available move it comes across. I was trying to have an AI working with the Minimax Algorithm. How do you think I can solve it?

Here's the code(w/ explanation):

A little insight before showing the code:

- I tried to set it all up in such a way that AI player(no matter what it's color is) is the maximizing player. So if the player turn is white, but white is the AI player, then isMaximizing = true.
- I wanted to point this out so that the player turn in terms of color and the player turn in terms of maximizing are not confused.

Where I initially use it:

```
// AI Hard - Return Minimax
function minimaxAI(){
    // Here's where the minimax function is initially called

    const AI = (ourPlayer === "white") ? "black" : "white"
    const squares = history[history.length - 1].slice()

    // AI is the maximizing player so we get -Infinity, it'll try to increase the value of bestScore
    let bestScore = -Infinity
    let bestMove = null
    // Perform minimax algorithm for each valid move and pick the best score
    
    // Get the valid moves for the AI player
    const AIValidMoves = checkSquaresForSides()[(AI === "black") ? 0 : 1 ]
    for (var AIMove=0;AIMove<AIValidMoves.length;AIMove++){

        // Play the AI moves and generate the new board
        const crds = AIValidMoves[AIMove].turned
        crds.unshift(AIValidMoves[AIMove].coordinates)
        const newBoard = handleMove(crds, squares,AI,false,false)

        // Check minimax for the new board
        const score = minimax(newBoard,4,false)
        
        // If score is higher than the current one, replace the highest score and the according coordinates
        if (score > bestScore || AIMove === 0) {
            bestScore = score
            bestMove = crds
        }
    }
    console.log('Final Value:')
    console.log(bestScore)

    // Play the move(this time on the real board)
    const upcomingAI = handleMove(bestMove)

    // Set it as the latest of the collection of squares
    setHistory(upcomingAI)

    // Useless to know for this issue
    setStepNumber(upcomingAI.length - 1)
}
```

The Minimax Algorithm Itself:

```
function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
    const AI = (ourPlayer === "white") ? "black" : "white"
    const stones = setStoneCount(board)
    
    // If there's a winner, return Infinity, 0 or -Infinity depending on whether AI won, it is a tie or our player won
    if (stones[0] === 0 || stones[1] === 0 || stones[0] + stones[1] === 64) {
        // Return the score of the move if the game is over
        let score = (stones[(AI === "black") ? 1 : 0] === 0) ? Infinity : (stones[stones[0] === stones[1]]) ? 0 : -Infinity
        return score
    } else if (depth === 0) {
        // If the maximal depth is reached, then evaluate the current board by counting all the stones for the both sides and subtracting one from the other appropriately
        const squares = setStoneCount(board)
        let score = 0
        if (AI === "black") {
            score = squares[0] - squares[1]
        } else if (AI === "white") {
            score = squares[1] - squares[0]
        }
        return score
    }
    if (isMaximizing) {
        // Perform minimax if depth !== 0 and isMaximizing, just like we did initially
        let bestScore = -Infinity
        
        // Get the valid moves for the maximizing player
        const AIValidMoves = checkSquaresForSides()[(AI === "black") ? 0 : 1 ] // AI Moves because isMaximizing = true
        for (var AIMove=0;AIMove<AIValidMoves.length;AIMove++){
            const crds = AIValidMoves[AIMove].turned
            crds.unshift(AIValidMoves[AIMove].coordinates)
            const newBoard = handleMove(crds,board,AI,false,false)
            // check for isMaximizing
            let maximizingNext = !isMaximizing
            
            // If there's no move to make for the one side, player turn might stay the same. Here, I check for those situations
            const available = checkSquaresForSides(newBoard)
            if (available[0].length === 0) {
                if (AI === "white") {
                    maximizingNext = true
                } else {
                    maximizingNext = false
                }
            } else if (available[1].length === 0){
                if (AI === "black") {
                    maximizingNext = true
                } else {
                    maximizingNext = false
                }
            }
            
            // Perform minimax for the new board(depth is one less)
            const score = minimax(newBoard,depth - 1,maximizingNext)
            
            // If current score is higher than the highest one caught yet, it should be replaced
            if (score > bestScore) {
                bestScore = score
            }
        }
        return bestScore
    } else {
        // Perform minimax if depth !== 0 and isMaximizing
        let bestScore = Infinity

        // Get the valid squares for the minimizing player
        const PlayerValidMoves = checkSquaresForSides()[(AI === "black") ? 1 : 0 ] // Player Moves because isMaximizing = false

        // Play each move one-by-one for the minimizing player
        for (var playerMove=0;playerMove<PlayerValidMoves.length;playerMove++) {
            const crds = PlayerValidMoves[playerMove].turned
            crds.unshift(PlayerValidMoves[playerMove].coordinates)
            const newBoard = handleMove(crds,board,ourPlayer,false,false)
            // check for isMaximizing
            let maximizingNext = !isMaximizing
            
            // Just like the previous one, check whether there's an exceptional situation to be considered with the player turn
            const available = checkSquaresForSides(newBoard)
            if (available[0].length === 0) {
                if (AI === "white") {
                    maximizingNext = true
                } else {
                    maximizingNext = false
                }
            } else if (available[1].length === 0){
                if (AI === "black") {
                    maximizingNext = true
                } else {
                    maximizingNext = false
                }
            }
            
            // Perform minimax for the new board
            const score = minimax(newBoard,depth - 1,maximizingNext)

            // If the current score is lower than the lowest one obtained so far, it should be replaced
            if (score < bestScore) {
                bestScore = score
            }
        }
        return bestScore
    }
}
```

It did work initially, but when I was dissatisfied with the way the board is evaluated when the depth is reached. I changed it, and now it doesn't work. I don't want to go back to the previous one because it's not accurate. But then why the AI player plays the first move it comes across but doesn't evaluate properly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, just changed the board evaluation section to this:

```
// The initial score
let score = 0
// value board for each square
const sq_val = [
    [160, -20,  20,   5,   5,  20, -20, 160],    
    [-20, -40,  -5,  -5,  -5,  -5, -40, -20],
    [20,  -5,  15,   3,   3,  15,  -5,  20],
    [5,  -5,   3,   3,   3,   3,  -5,   5],
    [5,  -5,   3,   3,   3,   3,  -5,   5],
    [20,  -5,  15,   3,   3,  15,  -5,  20], 
    [-20, -40,  -5,  -5,  -5,  -5, -40, -20],   
    [160, -20,  20,   5,   5,  20, -20, 160]
]

// Our stones' positions are looked for and the according values are added or substracted depending on whether the player found is the maximizing player or the minimizing player(AI Player: Maximizing, Our Player: Minimizing)
for (var row=0;row<8;row++)
    for (var col=0;col<8;col++) {
        if (board[row][col] === AI) {
            score += sq_val[row][col]
        } else if (board[row][col] === ourPlayer) {
            score -= sq_val[row][col]
        }
    }
}
// The score is returned
return score
```

By the way, the algorithm is now all set but it is not that accurate, for that I need to increase the depth of it; and also to do that, I have to implement alpha-beta pruning first so our computer won't overheat. Also making the function asynchronous will be better in terms of performance.